How to test doFn with mocks in java?
Is it possible to use mocks with doFn? I have a process method in a doFn that reads from a gcs bucket and I'd like to test this.
I tried using LocalStorageHelper but it doesn't support bucket get operations. I also tried using Mockito mocks but it seems the behavior is not being passed through the the doFn.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you are using the Beam FileSystems API to connect to GCS (which is the recommended approach), you can test a pipeline that includes the DoFn by providing a local path. Your function should simply write to the local file instead of GCS and that will allow you to test your logic.
